# ionic 5: camera getPhoto promise no result

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have the following code using angular + ionic 5:

```
Camera.getPhoto({
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
    source: CameraSource.Prompt,
    allowEditing: false,
    saveToGallery: false,
    quality: 100,
})
```

Which results in a promise. I can successfully take a photo using IOS14, but once I select to use it in the camera screen, nothing happens. This promise isn't rejected, it's not resolved. Try catching also doesn't log anything. The only problem I see is this in the xcode console (prior to taking a picture):

```
[Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}
```

and after I press use photo this is shown in the console:

```
TO JS {"exif":{"CompositeImage":2,"Flash":24,"MeteringMode":5,"OffsetTimeOriginal":"+02:00","OffsetTime":"+02:00","ExifVersion":"0232","SubjectArea":[2013,1511,2116,1270],"WhiteBalance":0,"SceneType":1,"ExposureMode":0,"ApertureValue":1.6959938131099002,"DateTim
```

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else also stumbles upon this.

In the end it was my fault. I wasn't resolving the promise :(

Comment: How did you "resolve the promise"? Can you share code please?